# NGXS Update value of deeply nested property

Tags: angular, ngxs

I´m working with Angular and NGXS on a simple application to let users create simple products with tags, but I´m struggling with updating the nested properties.

I have a `User` model with a `Product` array.

```js
export interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  products: Product[];
}
```

And the Product model has an array of tags.

```js
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  tags: Tag[];
}
```

And the Tag model has also some properties.

```js
export interface Tag {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

I want to be able to ADD, GET, UPDATE, REMOVE single Products or single Tags.

On the GitHub Documentation of NGXS (https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/docs/recipes/immutability-helpers.md) I found this examples which updates a simgle property in an array:

```js
export interface TrelloStateModel {
  tasks: {
    [taskId: string]: Task;
  };
}

export class TrelloState {
  @Action(UpdateDueDate)
  updateDueDate(ctx: StateContext<TrelloStateModel>, action: UpdateDueDate) {
    ctx.setState(
      patch({
        tasks: patch({
          [action.taskId]: patch({
            dates: patch({
              dueDate: action.dueDate
            })
          })
        })
      })
    );
  }
}
```

But I simply don´t know how to make this work for my object model. Is there a better alternative to this?

Comment: Have you looked at the rest of the state operators? https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/operators

Comment: Yeah, I usually use these operators, but they don´t help me for my deeply nested property. All these example just add, update or remove an entity to/from an array that isn´t nested.

Comment: @LukyFoggy did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain what I'd do to add a single product to the array of a specific user.

First, in your user.action.ts file, create an Add action:

```
export class AddProduct { 
   static readonly type = [Product] Add product to list
   constructor(public product: Product) {}
}
```

Then, in your user.state.ts implement the Add action:

```
@Action(UserActions.AddProduct)
addProduct(ctx: StateContext<User>, action: UserActions.AddProduct) {
   const state = ctx.getState()

   //check whether the product you want to add is already in the list
   if(state.products.find(p => p.id === action.id) {
       //don't try to add a product that is already in the list
   } else {
       ctx.setState(
           patch({
               products: append([action.product])
       )}
     )
   }
}
```

Both patch and append are state operators and you need to import them from '@ngxs/store/operators';
import { patch, append} from '@ngxs/store/operators';

If you want to update a deep nested object, you may have to use patch within another patch and so on.

Then on your user.page.ts I'd create the product and then call this.store.dispatch(UserActions.AddProduct(product)).